# React Поиск по сайту с множеством ключей

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs

У меня есть форма фильтра и на ней 20 checkbox. Данные я собираю в массив.
Как реализовать поиск по ключам взятые с массива.
На сайте раньше использовался поиск по названии услуги.
react-search-input.

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачу.

Может есть примеры.

Comment: Поиск по массиву? Да и у массива в js ключей нету, может вы про обьект?

Comment: Данные по услугам хранятся в json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const filter = (data : []) => {
    let newData = [];
    if(isByFirst){newData.push(data.filter(x => ...))}
    if(isBySecond){newData.forEach(x => if(!x.find(y => y.id == x.id)){ 
                                        newData.push(data.filter(x => ...))})}
    ....
    return newData;
}
```

мог немного ошибиться с кодом, писал на коленке. Суть логики - проверяем каждый пункт, докидывая данные в массив, если их там нет ещё. Array.find вернет undefined, если не найдет совпадений. Array.filter - наша фильтрация. Если нет особой логики, то упрощённый вариант - упихать в data.filter() всё.